# Session information used on my other project

Tags: php

I'm currently making two different, but pretty similar web-based applications. So I'm using PHP, and standard MySQL (MariaDB in my case because I use XAMPP but I guess two of them are similar to one another). FYAI, I'm building my apps on a local server which located just right in my PC.

So let's say my first project is Project1, and it is stored in localhost/project1. Meanwhile, the Project2 is in localhost/project2. Both of them have a login feature for different account/user.

So when they try to log in I do this. By the way, it's MVC.

```
class Auth extends Controller {
   public function index()
   {
      // verification such as prevent raw attempt with no post data, etc.

      // verify the username and password, header back if fail, blablabla, u know...

      // and then the following is if succeeded
      $_SESSION['login'] = true;
      $_SESSION['id'] = // user id;

   }
}
```

I used that similar system in both of my projects.

### The Problem

So I was trying to figure out how session work, and I log myself into the localhost/project1. And then I open localhost/project2. Surprisingly for me, I didn't need to type in my username and password in localhost/project2. I logged in already. These things gave me some concern. So these are my questions:

1. Did that happened because I develop my site on a local server in my very own computer?
2. Don't you guys think that anybody can break in to my site just by creating some simple procedural php code in their server like this:

   $_SESSION['login'] =true;
   // and other sessions

   and then just access that file, which make their session login value is 
   true, and other validation session index that i used, and then just 
   access my web site and logged in, like some man with big AK-47 in his 
   hand walks in right from the very front door of the white house with no 
   secret service notice and hold him down in custody?
3. Why is this really happening and how do you think I should fix it? I also have some timeout feature so I'm afraid any big changes would bother most of my construction but any suggestion is really welcome.

Sorry if my English is bad, or my php knowledge is pathetic. I'm new.

Comment: if you are using same session variable in both projects then both projects will be accessible by one user id and password and if your user are coming from db and same user entry is present in both projects then it will be accessible otherwise you will get some error .

Comment: and does it also apply if the server is not in my pc? #justwandering

Comment: if you are using both projects in same server then yes

Comment: so if I just separate them in a different server it will be just okay?

Comment: so if I just separate them in a different server it will be just okay? 
Ans - Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sessions are normally driven by a cookie that contains your session ID. Since cookies are shared within the same domain by default, if you have two projects both located on the same host/domain (e.g. localhost), and both use sessions, then they will both share the same cookie and thus the same session data.

This means someone could NOT hack into your site by setting up a random session in their own site. Their session data would only be applicable to their own site.

On a side note, it's not usually a good idea to suggest analogies that involve storming the white house with a gun. Just a friendly piece of advice.

Comment: Oooh... okay got it... I had this perspective that different folder inside htdocs considered different host adresses, so I was wrong...